# table design for display content

Tags: mysql, database-design, php, table

In my previous work station, I saw them have a table design across all website they have worked on displaying editor content like this:

```
column|page_id| title |content_1|... |content_n| lang  |update_date|...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
row   |   1   |varchar|   text  |text|  text   |tinyint|  datetime |
......
```

> where `content_n` column are determined by the max editor it overall
>   has on that website.
>
> For an example: If the website generally has 1 editable content per
>   page but in addition, there is one page that has 4 editable content,
>   they will have 4 `content_n` column.

**The problem(imo):**

For pages that have only 1 editable content area, only `content_1` will be filled, and other column `content_n` will be `empty`. In addition, with multiple languages involve, those empty field add up.

**My question:**

1. Is this a good design of choice?
2. Wouldn't those empty column create unnecessary overhead?
3. What would be an improved table design when have a table such as this?

**My thought :**

I will probably merge all the content and title into one single column(mediumtext/longtext) and use `json_encode/array` to differentiate the content.

they use`mysql(MYISAM)` for all database engineer, and I prefer `Innodb`..if that is matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not build arrays as columns.  Instead, use extra tables.  If the different `content_*` are differeng languages, have another table with `page_id` (for JOINing), `content`, and `lang`.  Probably the `PRIMARY KEY` would be `(page_id, lang)`.